# Is "Louder With Crowder" the "#1 Conservative Daily Show"?

Tags: united-states, media

Steven Crowder in [his twitter bio](https://twitter.com/scrowder) claims to have the "#1 Conservative Daily Show".

Assuming he means #1 in audience (as any other claim is trivially meaningless) is this true? Does he have the largest audience of conservative TV or radio shows that are daily?

Comment: It could alternatively be the earliest in the day, at 7AM PT.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. That's not what #1 usually means unless he is deliberately trying tk be disingenuous

Comment: As far as I can tell, *Louder With Crowder* is only a podcast now - it doesn't appear to have had a TV show since 2022.

Comment: This sounds like common advertising [puffery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffery), like saying "the best burgers in town". Unless he's claiming to be #1 in some specific category I don't think this is answerable, or even intended to be taken literally.

Comment: When someone claims themselves #1, it's pomp. When someone else claims they're #1, that's news.

Comment: Also anyone can claim to be the "#1 conservative daily show" by just declaring all bigger shows to be "not really conservative".

Comment: @DJClayworth: one might say that to be taken half-seriously in the post-2016 ecosystem, one has to use Trumpian claims, or else be regarded as "not really conservative", LOL.